# Relaying opinion in Indirect speech

Tags: indirect-speech

How do you relay an information like this using the indirect speech. For example:

> David said: "Gone are the days when people could speak good grammar, nowadays, people are just too lazy to try".

If I am to relay this using the indirect speech format, how will I rephrase it?

Comment: I don't think I would even try. I would just quote what he said, because an attempt to use indirect speech would not capture the flavor of the original.

Comment: So you're saying you can remember what someone has said word for word and relay it when having a conversation, even if it just came to your mind to use it.

Comment: Using  strict 'indirect speech rules'  also requires one to remember,  word for word, what was said. A paraphrase of somebody does not require such a memory.

Comment: Indirect speech means paraphrasing. I'm not a machine to remember things exactly as it was said. Whoever made the "strict indirect speech rule" was just a joker. People relay things that was said everyday and I'm sure they relay it using their own words and not in the exact way it was said.  Or do you do differently, Claire?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has said in a comment that "Indirect speech means paraphrasing" and "Whoever made the 'strict indirect speech rule'  was just a joker," which seems to mean that the OP is asking about paraphrasing, which is opinion-based, and not actual indirect speech, which actually does follow rules. So I think the question **unclear** and possibly self-contradicting (rephrase the sentence using indirect speech but don't use indirect speech rules).

Answer (score 1):

What an interesting question.  My response is in three parts.

1. As is often the case with indirect speech, you cannot retain the nuance in the poetic phrasing “gone are the days” with its choriambic rhythm.
2. Finding a way to represent ‘nowadays’ is a headache.  I have done my best, given that ‘thenadays’ does not exist (yet!).
3. The indirect version is as follows:-  “ the days were gone when people could speak good grammar.  In recent times, people were just too lazy to try.”. If you really wanted to preserve the poetic flourish, you might get away with:  “Gone were the days <,she said,> when people ...  A commentator might call it poetic licence!

Comment: Thanks but in a case where I believe what was said to be the truth, at least the truth in my opinion, can I retain the present tense in the sentence even when using indirect speech. For example, You said Gone were the days when people could speak good English. Can I change were to are and could to can, since I believe this is true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Timmy, you can, provided you think what was said is true now.  For example, “Copernicus understood that the Earth goes round the Sun.”.